# Trying to Print and Save all the Records in Separate files

Tags: ms-access, vba

Code below prints and saves  only one project at the Record, how can I make it to Print and save all of them at once?

```
Private Sub PrintProject_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
      Dim MyPath As String
      Dim MyFileName As String
      Dim MyProjectNumber As String
      Dim MyProjectName As String

      MyPath = "C:\Reports\"

      MyProjectNumber = Me!ProjectNumber
      MyProjectName = Me!ProjectName
      MyFileName = MyProjectNumber & " " & MyProjectName & ".PDF"
      With DoCmd
      .OpenReport _
      ReportName:="Total Report", _
      View:=acViewPreview, _
      WhereCondition:="ProjectNumber = " &  & MyProjectNumber &  Chr(34)
      .OutputTo _
      ObjectType:=acOutputReport, _
      OutputFormat:=acFormatPDF, _
      ObjectName:="Total Report", _
      Outputfile:=MyPath & MyFileName

      .Close acReport, "Total Report"
     End With

     End Sub
```

Comment: thnx Simoco, I was editing when your Edit came up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the Solution, Simple

```
       DoCmd.OpenReport "Total Report", acViewPreview, , _ 
      "ProjectNumber='" & !ProjectNumber & "'" _
       DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Total Report", _
       acFormatPDF, MyPath & MyFileName _
       DoCmd.Close acReport, "Total Report"
```